# without X and without Y

Tags: conjunctions, negation, logic

I want to express absence of 2 things. For example:

> It was a pretty day without rain and without snow.

Logically: (not X) and (not Y), which is equivalent to: not (X or Y)

Therefore, I guess the following might be correct:

> It was a pretty day without rain or snow.

Is that correct? Is it necessary/better to indicate more clearly that both things are missing?

Comment: "Without rain or snow" is fine.

Comment: Although not strictly necessary, for better comprehension I'd add a comma after "day." Thus, "It was a pretty day, without rain or snow." You could also remove the "it" and say, "The day was pretty, without rain or snow." (I've gotten into the habit of getting rid of the indefinite "it" whenever I can. There's no inherent grammatical benefit in doing that, but I like the challenge. So for example, I'd change "It doesn't matter how much or how little money you have, Fred" to "How much or how little money you have does not matter, Fred." Don

Comment: @rhetorician Do you also avoid sentence-ending prepositions, or is that the kind of foolishness up with which you will not put?

Comment: FYI, the logical equivalence you're referring to is called [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). It's not always applied the same way in English as in logic.